# Check for a property inside a collection of type IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am trying to find whether a collection of type `IEnumerable` contains a property or not.

Assuming `RowModels` is a collection of type `IEnumerable`, I have ...

```
  foreach (var items in RowModels) {
       if (items.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Contains(items.GetType().GetProperty("TRId").Name) ) 
        {
               // do something...
        }
    }
```

I get the error

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' 
and the best extension method overload has some invalid arguments.
```

Comment: Okay, and does it work?  If so, why the question?  If not, what happens, do you get an error?  Is your output not what was expected?  If so, explain what the expected and actual output was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Any()`:

```
foreach (var items in RowModels) {
   if(items.GetType().GetProperties().Any(prop => prop.Name == "TRId") ) 
    {
           // do something...
    }
}
```

That being said, you can also just check for the property directly:

```
foreach (var items in RowModels) {
   if(items.GetType().GetProperty("TRId") != null) 
    {
           // do something...
    }
}
```

Also - if you're looking for items in `RowModels` that implement a specific interface or are of some specific class, you can just write:

```
foreach (var items in RowModels.OfType<YourType>())
{
   // do something
}
```

The `OfType<T>()` method will automatically filter to just the types that are of the specified type.  This has the advantage of giving you strongly typed variables, as well.

Comment: Looks like you were faster =)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `if` to:

```
if(items.GetType().GetProperty("TRId") != null)
//yeah, there is a TRId property
else
//nope!
```